# How can I integrate a stepper motor into my ROS robot's camera functionality using Python and threads?

Tags: python, ros

Im working on a robot with a camera function. Im using ROS with python and now i want to implement my stepper motor to turn certain steps when on the right and the opposite steps on the left. Im using threads but im really new with this.

The core Code is working like this:
a cameramodule recognizes black. if a black line is in the middle of the camera, i print "on track". when left it prints "turn right". same for the right. Now i want to change the print with the stepper code.

my code is basically resetting the turn right command. so when im on left. it continoues to run 30 degrees instead of stopping when reaching them.

Here is the code snippet that isnt working:

```
from RpiMotorLib import RpiMotorLib
motor=Rpi.MotorLib.A4988Nema(21,20, [26,19,12], "DRV8825")
def __init__(self):
...

def processed_image(self, cv_image):
global flag
...
if cx >160: #left
left = threading.Thread(target=self.turn_left)
flag = 1
left.start()

if cx <= 160 and cx >96:
reset = threading.Thread(target=self.turn_reset)
if flag != 0:
flag = 0
reset.start()

if cx <=96:
right = threading.Thread(target=self.turn_right)
flag = 2
right.start()
...

# Threads
def turn_reset(self):
global flag
if flag == 1:
motor.motor_go(False,"Full",30,0.005,False, 0.0005)
if elif flag == 2:
motor.motor_go(True,"Full",30, 0.005,False, 0.0005)
flag = 0
reset_event.set()

def turn_right(self):
global flag
motor.motor_go(False,"Full",30,0.005,False,0.0005)
flag = 0
right_event.set()

def turn_left(self):
global flag
motor.motor_go(True,"Full",30,0.005,False,0.0005)
flag = 0
left_event.set()
```

Maybe there is a easier way for this. Do you have an idea?

creating new events (right_event.set() for example) and using a if not right_event.is_set() statement.